# INSERT...SELECT FROM Mysql statement error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a list of items in a table that have ids, and I want to put them into a item_to_group table, all with a specific group number.

My MySQL code is:

```
INSERT INTO `item_to_item_group` (`items`.`id`, 3476)
SELECT `id`
FROM `items`
```

But I'm getting the old "You have an error in your SQL syntax" message. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what "3476" is for.  Do you want to insert id 3476 into the `items_to_item_group` table?  (If so, why is the select needed?)  Do you want to insert all `id` values from `items` into the new table?  (If so, what is 3476 meant to do?)

Comment: @SimpleCoder please don't just remove the tag, if the question is obviously too localized then vote to close as well

Comment: @bluefeet: Good point - will do. (I'll go back to ones I previously processed as well)

Comment: @SimpleCoder Thanks for being reasonable.  If they are good questions and not too localized, then feel free to leave them open.

Comment: Why was this question suddenly downvoted? Twice? Over a month since I wrote it? This is a pretty useful feature of Mysql and to beginners, it's not at all obvious how to do it.

Comment: @Lars: There was a site-wide cleanup of the mysql-error-1064 tag last week. Although it's a useful feature, there were *literally* over 1000 other questions wondering about the same error. I didn't downvote this, but it's possible someone who was cleaning up tags did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it should be the column name instead of value,

```
INSERT  INTO item_to_item_group (id, columnameHere) -- <== define columnName here
SELECT  id, 3476
FROM    items
```